# Understand price impact and liquidity in pancakeswap

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, uniswap, bsc, pancakeswap

I am trying to understand how the price impact and liquidity was calculated in uniswap or pancakeswap through the router contract?

**UNI Router: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d**

**Pancake Router: https://bscscan.com/address/0x05ff2b0db69458a0750badebc4f9e13add608c7f**

Is there is any direct method or what calculations need to do in my code? Pl. Guide me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: [We have ready Python code examples for PancakeSwap price impact calculations](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/uniswap_v2/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.fees.html#module-eth_defi.uniswap_v2.fees). They also work with other Uniswap v2 compatible DEXes.

Answer (score 19):

**Disclaimer**: I don't think this is the correct method to calculate the price impact but it's almost 100% accurate for price impacts of less than 1%. This calculation method assumes that multi-hop is disabled i.e. swapping is restricted to direct pairs. I've only tested this calculation method on PancakeSwap and it is less accurate for larger trade sizes compared to what is shown on their website. Attempting to calculate trade sizes for a 2% price impact, showed 1.99% on the PancakeSwap UI, 5% showed 4.99%, and 10% showed 9.97%. While these discrepancies could be attributed to the user interface lagging, I'm not confident that's the only reason. If anyone can better explain what's happening, I'd be very eager to know.

### Short answer

Given a liquidity pool with token A and token B, let:

- `reserve_a_initial` be the amount of token A in the liquidity
  pool before the trade
- `reserve_b_initial` be the amount of token B in the liquidity
  pool before the trade (not required to calculate the price impact)
- `fee` be the trading fee. For PancakeSwap, this is `0.0025`
- `amount_traded` be the amount of token A traded

To calculate the price impact:

```
amountInWithFee = amount_traded * (1 - fee);
price_impact = amountInWithFee / (reserve_a_initial + amountInWithFee);
```

### Explanation

[This article](https://dailydefi.org/articles/price-impact-and-how-to-calculate/) explains how to calculate the price impact. However, please note that what the article refers to as the "current market price" or "market rate", I refer to as the `mid_price`. Now, let's calculate the `price_impact`:

```
constant_product = reserve_a_initial * reserve_b_initial;
reserve_b_after_execution = constant_product / (reserve_a_initial + amountInWithFee);
amountOut = reserve_b_initial - reserve_b_after_execution;
market_price = amountInWithFee / amountOut;
mid_price = reserve_a_initial / reserve_b_initial;
price_impact = 1 - (mid_price / market_price);
```

Before substituting and simplifying, let:

- `reserve_a_initial` be [image]
- `reserve_b_initial` be [image]
- `reserve_b_after_execution` be [image]
- `amount_traded` be [image]
- `fee` be [image]
- `amountInWithFee` be [image]
- `constant_product` be [image]
- `amountOut` be [image]
- `market_price` be [image]
- `mid_price` be [image]
- `price_impact` be [image]

Now for the math:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I found this mind-blowing, but the amount of token B in the pool doesn't affect the `price_impact`. However, `reserve_b_initial` will affect `amount_out`.

### Calculating `amount_traded` given the `price_impact`

Rearranging the `price_impact` equation, it is possible to calculate `amount_traded` for a given `price_impact`:

[image]

### Slippage and minimum amount received

To account for slippage, `s`, and calculate the minimum received, `amount_out_min`:

```
amount_out_min = amount_out * (1 - s);
```

Slippage does not affect `price_impact`.

### Sample code

I don't know if there's a function in a PancakeSwap contract that will directly return the `price_impact`, but you can get the reserves of a pool and then calculate it. Let's take CAKE-USDT as an example:

```js
import { Contract, utils, providers } from 'ethers';
const poolAddress = '0xa39af17ce4a8eb807e076805da1e2b8ea7d0755b'; // CAKE-USDT
const poolContract = new Contract(
    poolAddress,
    ['function getReserves() public view returns (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1, uint32 _blockTimestampLast)'],
    new providers.WebSocketProvider(PROVIDER_URL)
);

poolContract.getReserves()
    .then((reserves) => {
        let reserve_a_initial = parseFloat(utils.formatUnits(reserves._reserve0));
        let reserve_b_initial = parseFloat(utils.formatUnits(reserves._reserve1));
        console.log(`CAKE in pool: ${reserve_a_initial}`);
        console.log(`USDT in pool: ${reserve_b_initial}`);

        const fee = 0.0025;
        let max_price_impact = 0.01;
        let amount_traded_cake = reserve_a_initial * max_price_impact / ((1 - max_price_impact)*(1 - fee));
        let amount_traded_usdt = reserve_b_initial * max_price_impact / ((1 - max_price_impact)*(1 - fee));
        console.log(`Given a max price impact of ${max_price_impact*100}%, the max amount of CAKE tradeable is ${amount_traded_cake}`);
        console.log(`Given a max price impact of ${max_price_impact*100}%, the max amount of USDT tradeable is ${amount_traded_usdt}`);

        let amountInCAKE = amount_traded_cake * (1 - fee);
        let amountInUSDT = amount_traded_usdt * (1 - fee);
        let price_impact_trade_cake = amountInCAKE / (reserve_a_initial + amountInCAKE);
        let price_impact_trade_usdt = amountInUSDT / (reserve_b_initial + amountInUSDT);
        console.log(`Price impact when trading ${amount_traded_cake} CAKE: ${price_impact_trade_cake*100}%`);
        console.log(`Price impact when trading ${amount_traded_usdt} USDT: ${price_impact_trade_usdt*100}%`);
    }).catch(console.error);
```

Sample results:

```
CAKE in pool: 1030240.4016832297
USDT in pool: 19974605.474162016
Given a max price impact of 1%, the max amount of CAKE tradeable is 10432.550079068678
Given a max price impact of 1%, the max amount of USDT tradeable is 202269.36507087937
Price impact when trading 10432.550079068678 CAKE: 1%
Price impact when trading 202269.36507087937 USDT: 1%
```

[image: price impact at 1%]

Please note that the price shown on the PancakeSwap UI is the `execution_price`:

```
execution_price = amount_traded / amountOut;
```

Comment: One of the best written answers on stackexchange! clap clap.

Comment: hi, somehow for me the 2 different ways of calculating price impact are not giving the same numbers. If we take first example of the article you linked we should get the same number if $10000 / (2000000 + 10000) = 1 - (2000 / 2009.64)$ which is not correct?

Comment: @Chris the article has some rounding errors. reserve_b_after_execution should be approx. 995.024876. amountOut (ETH received) should be approx. 4.975124. market_price (Price paid per ETH) should be exactly 2010. Thus, 10000 / (2000000 + 10000) = 1 - (2000 / 2010)

Comment: Thanks for this clear solution! really saved me a ton of time.

Comment: The only thing missing in this answer is that the fee actually goes into the pool, so the constant product does change a little bit. That is probably why it is ever so slightly off in some cases. Excellent answer btw. I would love to see how this could be tweaked to find the optimal order quantity for an arbitrage trade.

Answer (score 1):

[Adding this as a separate answer, due to lack of reputation for comments]

The answer by `vlj614` is great. There is just one minor thought error and that also explains why your price impact is slightly off, specifically for large trades.

To calculate the impact, you are taking `p_market` as reference point (=denominator), i.e. you calculate the % difference from the realized price to the initial mid-price (`p_mid`). Instead, your formula should be the other way around and use `p_mid` as the reference, because the user is interested in how far (in %) the swap moves the price away from `p_mid`.

The correct formula would then be: `p_mid / p_market - 1`

To illustrate with a numerical example, assume the mid-price before the swap is 2000 USDC per ETH. Given the other parameters (pool reserves etc.), let's say the swap execution realizes at `p_market = 2200`. The intuitive answer to the price impact is `= 10%`, because my execution happened at 10% above the mid-price. Or expressed with the suggested new formula: `impact = 2200/2000 - 1 = 10%`.

According to your formula however, the price impact would instead be `= 1 - 2000/2200 = 9.09%`.

Answer (score 0):

.17% is added back to the pool, so we need to figure out how to split that up in order to get the exact rate of exchange. It's confusing me, because the rate is used in the calculation of rate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answers，I changed something.
In UniswapV2 Module,this is a demo

```
function calculate() {
    let reserve_a_initial = 9266.898548529131779247;
    let reserve_b_initial = 0.3837704022282708;
    console.log(`TokenA in pool: ${reserve_a_initial}`);
    console.log(`TokenB in pool: ${reserve_b_initial}`);
    const amount_traded_cake = 100;
    const realInput = amount_traded_cake * 0.997;
    let amount_traded_usdt =
        (realInput * reserve_b_initial) / (reserve_a_initial + realInput);
    console.log(`the max amount of TokenA tradeable is ${amount_traded_cake}`);
    console.log(` the max amount of TokenB tradeable is ${amount_traded_usdt}`);
    let price_impact_trade_cake = (realInput * 100) / (reserve_a_initial + realInput);
    let price_impact_trade_usdt = amount_traded_usdt * 0.997 / (reserve_b_initial + (amount_traded_usdt * 0.997));
    console.log(`Price impact when trading ${amount_traded_cake} TokenA: ${price_impact_trade_cake}%`);
    console.log(`Price impact when trading ${amount_traded_usdt} TokenB: ${price_impact_trade_usdt * 100}%`);
}
```

and solidity demo

```
function getDeep(
    uint256 inTokenANum,
    uint256 tokenAReserve,
    uint256 tokenBReserve,
    uint8 decimals
) public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 maxOutAmount = router02.getAmountOut(
        inTokenANum,
        tokenAReserve,
        tokenBReserve
    );
    uint256 realInput = (inTokenANum * 997) / 1000;
    // accuracy mul 1000000
    uint256 slippage = (realInput * 1000000) / (tokenAReserve + realInput);
    return slippage;
}
```

This may be slightly different from the webpage, but what I can think of may be caused by a sliding point issue