# How to calculate amount needed for a specific percentage change of price impact in Uniswap v3

Tags: uniswap, sqrtpricelimitx96

I want to get the amount needed to make a 1% price impact in uniswap v3 pool, also add how to calc price impact would help

i found that [Understand price impact and liquidity in pancakeswap](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102063/understand-price-impact-and-liquidity-in-pancakeswap) but its for uniswap v2